# Edit controls for different types

Tags: wpf, object, controls, types, edit

I need to let the user edit different types of objects.
Are there any existing libraries that have edit-controls for types ranging from float, bool, int, string, filename, color etc. ?

(preferably with features like validation, range-checking etc.)

It's not hard to find / create these controls individually, but if there are standard / existing ones that have already been proven in the field that would be very nice :)